# コマンドプロンプトでHeroku CLIが使えない

Tags: windows, heroku

以下ページから64ビット版のインストーラーを使ってインストール完了し、コマンドプロンプトで `heroku` と打ったら以下のようなエラーがでます。解決方法を教えてください。

https://devcenter.heroku.com/ja/articles/heroku-cli

```
'heroku' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

Comment: 前提条件として Git のインストールも必要と記載がありますが、こちらはインストール済みですか？

Comment: git はインストールしております！

Answer (score 1):

herokuの**インストール前**にあらかじめコマンドプロンプトを開いた場合、herokuインストール完了後に`heroku --version`などをコマンド実行するとご質問のエラーが発生します。
コマンドプロンプトを新たに開きなおしてエラーが解消しているかご確認ください。

蛇足ですが、これは該当のコマンドプロンプトに`heroku.exe`のパスが反映されていないことが原因です。
コマンドプロンプトを開きなおして`echo %PATH%`を入力すると、標準インストール後には末尾に`;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin`が追加されます。
このパス追加処理はインストールオプション(`Set PATH to heroku`チェックボックス)で変更できます。標準でこのオプションにチェックが入っているので考えにくいですが、コマンドプロンプトを立ち上げなおしてもエラーが解消しない場合はこのチェックを外していてパスが追加されていない可能性もあります。

コマンドプロンプトが`heroku`や`notepad`と入力を受け付けると、カレントディレクトリや`%PATH%`のフォルダを順番に検索して`heroku.exe`を探していきます。
パスはコマンドプロンプト起動時に読み込まれ、起動中に自動で再読み込みはされないため、パスが追加される前に開いたコマンドプロンプトではherokuの場所を特定できないことがエラーの原因となります。